# Wordpress vers 5.2. and Ajax Bad request 400

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using the new version of Wordpress 5.2 and I need to call an ajax request, but it does not work. I get an error message in the console: **bad request 400**.

**This is the js code:**

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url : test_ajax.url,
data: {
    action: 'say_hello_test',
    security : test_ajax.security,
    valore_trasmesso : 'Hello world!'
},
success: function( data ) {
    // Insert code
},
error: function( error ) {
    // Insert code
}
```

});

**This is the code in the functions.php file**

```
function enqueue_ajax_script_test()
{
wp_localize_script( 'script_ajax_test', 'test_ajax', array(
   'url'      => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
   'security' => wp_create_nonce('ajax_test_nonce_string')
 ));
}
add_action( "wp_enqueue_scripts", "enqueue_ajax_script_test" );


function say_hello_test_callback()
{
check_ajax_referer( 'sct_nonce_key', 'security' );

$parametro_ajax = trim( $_POST['valore_trasmesso'] );
echo $parametro_ajax;

wp_send_json( array( 'responso' => 'callback eseguita' ) );
die();
}
// Logged users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_say_hello_test', 'say_hello_test_callback' );
// Not logged users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_say_hello_test', 'say_hello_test_callback' );
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of errors in the code that will prevent this from working correctly. The immediate issue that's resulting in a HTTP 400 error is that `test_ajax.url` doesn't exist in the given context so the AJAX request has no URL property.

## `wp_localize_script()`

To use this function, you must give it the handle of a script you want to attach the data to. If you don't attach it to a script, the JavaScript object won't be fired up on the frontend.

Solution: use `wp_enqueue_script()` to load a JS file and attach it to that.

Example:

```
function enqueue_ajax_script_test() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script_ajax_test', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script_ajax_test.js', ['jquery'], '1.0.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'script_ajax_test'...
```

Modify the above as necessary. Perhaps you're already enqueueing your custom JS elsewhere and just need to drop that in. If you're embedding JS in your templates, maybe a custom JS file is the way to go. Either way, to use `wp_localize_script`, you're going to need a script to attach it to.

## `check_ajax_referer()`

With the JavaScript object making it through to the frontend and the AJAX request now firing off correctly, we need to deal with the next roadblock. If `check_ajax_referer` fails, you're going to get a HTTP 403 response back.

In the script above it will fail because you create a nonce under one name and then check it as another. In `wp_localize_script`, it gets created as `ajax_test_nonce_string` so that's the name you need to test for.

```
check_ajax_referer( 'ajax_test_nonce_string', 'security' );
```

## How are you going to respond to the AJAX call?

In your case you both output directly (echo) and use `wp_send_json()`. Your response type can't be both a string and JSON.

`wp_send_json()` will also handle exiting for you. This can be simplified to:

```
function say_hello_test_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax_test_nonce_string', 'security' );
    wp_send_json([
        'responso' => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['valore_trasmesso'] ),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply...the problem unfortunatelly has not been solved...

Comment: @sodskat I'm afraid that doesn't give me enough to go on to try and help debug further. If you type test_ajax.url into the console, what does it give you back?

Comment: it gives me back: http://localhost/biz-rest/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php